# laravel blade form show me an exception error

Tags: laravel

First of all sorry for my bad english.
I have a laravel form using blade template engine that show me an exception error. If i remove the code and use the php form with echo statmente everything fine and the page show up.
where is the problem? Here is my code

```
{{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'news')) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
    {{ Form::title('name', Input::old('title'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
    {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('description'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

{{ Form::submit('Create the Nerd!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: After reading Alley Shairus answer: If you use any kind of IDE (Intelligent Development Enviroment), it will show you such errors. And reading the docs first, is always a good idea

Comment: sorry the textmethod change to titlw when refactoring the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as Form::title() in laravel.

Try this

```
{{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'news')) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
    {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('title'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
    {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('description'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

{{ Form::submit('Create the Nerd!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Make sure you figure these errors yourself as these are typing mistakes.

Comment: soory it's from a tutorial http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers